# Confusion using Add Rasters To Mosaic Dataset Tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, landsat

I am trying to use **Add Rasters To Mosaic Dataset** but I am facing a small issue. First image shows the tool and all of my Input Data. Second image, shows the result after I executed the tool. Third image, is the result which I would like to have when the execution of the tool ends, but instead I get this **dark** second image. I tried to change band combination in the second image but I couldn't make it any brighter. Any ideas how to get the third image as the output of the **Tool**?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try rebuilding overviews, but do NOT use the default "nearest neighbour" interpolation.  It's been horrifically buggy for mosaic overviews for many years, and ESRI seems to have no interest in fixing it.  (This may not be the cause of the issue, but it is worth trying to at least rule it out.)  It's also worth zooming right into the native scale of the image (where overviews are not used) to see if it then appears correctly.

Comment: I think that it's the use of the Surface Reflectance. From ESRI: When you add Landsat 8 Surface Reflectance and ARD data to a mosaic dataset, a function is available in the raster dataset properties to add a mask. This mask allows you to mask out unwanted image data values that can affect subsequent raster functions such as negative values.